# closeness of matrices

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, matrix-calculus, random-matrices

I'm really lost in math and would really appreciate any help with the following problem. Denote as $S_{+}(p)$ the set of all positively defined symmetric real-valued matrices of size $p \times p$.  And let $(A_1,..., A_n)$ be an iid sample, s.t. $A_i \in S_{+}(p)$ for all $1 \leq i \leq n$. Furthermore, there exists a matrix $B \in S_{+}(p)$, s.t.

$\|B - \frac{1}{n}{\sum_{i = 1}^n}(B A_i)^{1/2} \| \leq \frac{C}{\sqrt{n}}$,
where $\| \cdot \|$ is just some matrix norm, e.g. Frobenius.

The question is whether it is possible to state anything about the closeness of $B$ and $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}A_i$ in terms of sample-size? Something like

$\|B -  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}F(A_i)\| \leq \frac{R}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $F(x)$ is a some function, e.g. $F(x) = \sqrt{x}$ or $= x^2$.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: What is $(BA_i)^{1/2}$ ?   You write "there exists $B$..."; yes, take $B=0$...

Comment: I wanted to write: take  $B=aI_n$ where $a$ is a small positive real.

Comment: @loupblanc $B$ is positively defined and symmetric, thus $B = 0$ does not work :(. Furthermore it is not obvious at all, that $B$ is close or equal to any $aI_n$, I mean this assumption seems to be too restrictive.

Comment: @ Alex, you are not serious. Read my second post. About the first one, do you know how to define $(BA)^{1/2}$  ? I'm curious to see it...

Comment: @loupblanc, you're right, of course. But originally $B$ comes as a solution of some fixed-point equation, that can be different from $aI_p$. I completely admit that the problem might be unresolvable in general case.